# Black Screen on International Video Calls with Agora.io and Flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm trying to make a video call abroad on my Flutter project but even though call has successfully created and both sides have connected there is no video or audio on both sides.
I'm using Agora.io as RTC Engine and my project is a test project (I only have the app id).
Do I need to have certificate and token or is there any other solutions?

Agora version: 3.1.3